# Any other way to use self-join without cross apply in update?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to do a self join with aggregate function, in the beginning i was using a while to do this but performance was horrible , so i prefer a  cross join , even now my performance is high.

```
create function dbo.get_max_maket_mapping_unique_id  (@market_cat_id int)
returns @val table (uni_id int)
as  
begin       
insert into @val
select max(isnull(unique_id,0))+1
from maket_mapping_unique_four
where market_cat_id = @market_cat_id

return     
end



update t1
    set t1.unique_id = uni_id
from 
    maket_mapping_unique_four t1
cross apply  dbo.get_max_maket_mapping_unique_id (t1.market_cat_id) c
```

Comment: I need to be done , Can some one help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a sequence number for each "market cat".  If so, then just use window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select muf.*,
             row_number() over (partition by market_cat_id order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from maket_mapping_unique_four muf
    )
update toupdate
    set unique_id = seqnum;
```

Comment: It Does't Make sense.. hope you under stand below query.